# jQuery populating dropdown using array, multiple arrays

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm populating a single select dropdown and using an array to populate the dropdown as follows:

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'Albuquerque Aero (NM75)',
    val2 : 'Albuquerque FM&T (NM14)',
    val3 : 'Allentown (PA19)'
};
```

At the moment the dropdown 'value' and 'text' uses the same information pulled from the above array as follows:

```
$('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
```

I need to have a different piece of information shown in the 'text' element so I wanted to use a multi-array as opposed to two separate arrays (more efficient?) but I'm struggling to get my head around multi-arrays in Javascript/ jQuery.

Is it as simple as:

```
var myOptions = {
        val1 : 'Albuquerque Aero (NM75)','Different text',
        val2 : 'Albuquerque FM&T (NM14)','Different text',
        val3 : 'Allentown (PA19)','Different text'
    };
```

How could I achieve what I am looking for?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to modify the structure of your object (as of now its not valid).

You can create an array of objects with `value` and `text` which can be iterated and `option` can be created.

```js
var myOptions = [{
  val: 'Albuquerque Aero (NM75)',
  text: 'Different text (NM75)'
}, {
  val: 'Albuquerque FM&T (NM14)',
  text: 'Different text (NM14)'
}, {
  val: 'Allentown (PA19)',
  text: 'Different text (PA19)'
}];

$.each(myOptions, function(index, item) {
  $('<option />', {
    html: item.text,
    value: item.val
  }).appendTo('select');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Comment: Appreciated Satpal - thanks for the additional feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of arrays, better you use `JSON`.
Try changing your source of values to a json object and loop through the object to fill select list

```
var myOptions = [
    {"val" : "Albuquerque Aero (NM75)", "text": "something"},
    {"val" : "Albuquerque FM&T (NM14)", "text": "something"},
    {"val" : "Allentown (PA19)", "text": "something"}
];

$(myOptions).each(function(i, e){
    $("#mySelect").append($("<option>").val(e.val).text(e.text));
});
```

check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zk0uc98o/1/)